# Linux Based Platform suitable for Architects

Tags: distribution-choice

We are an architectural firm and wish to use Linux based platform on our desktops. The Softwares used would be Draftsight, 3dmax, sketchup, tally & office. Which platform is best suited for our needs and what would be the ideal system requirements for the same. Thanks & regards..

Comment: What are your needs? The ideal system requirements would be the system requirements for the software you mentioned.

Comment: We primarily and extensively use Draftsight for 2d drafting and Sketchup for 3d.. Have tried using libreoffice for presentation but had a little hassle whilst working on the same comparing MS Office,. Maybe we are not so conversant & may need to adapt. These are the basic softwares we use. We may need jpeg correcting softwares too..

Answer (score 1):

First off, some of the software you list doesn't have Linux ports. Draftsight has beta binaries released for [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop) and [Fedora](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/). Microsoft Office isn't supported on Linux and you'd probably be looking at switching to something like [Libreoffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/). Tally, Google Sketchup & 3ds Max doesn't have native ports. You can probably run them with [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)) but smooth operation isn't guaranteed.

Secondly, I couldn't possibly tell you what distribution you'd want to use, much less the ideal system requirements. If all your needs are the software you mentioned, then we have a problem since most aren't supported on Linux. This means that **if** you do get them running with Wine, the system requirements mentioned on the software's websites might differ from what actually will be needed.

The best way to go about this is to actually try it out. Download something user friendly such as [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop), [Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/) or [Fedora](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/) ([of course more exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution#Popular_distributions)), install the software you need and see how it works.

Comment: Thanks, Roxto... Have read that Linux Mint with MATE (or Cinnamon) OR Kubuntu would be helpful for our requirements. Please suggest. Also could you recommend alternative software for 3d drafting which is comparable to Sketchup.. Thanks

Comment: @user495480 I think either of those would be a good choice. For the software, I've barely ever used any 3D sketching software so I couldn't really help with that, but maybe [this](https://alternativeto.net/software/google-sketchup/?platform=linux) could give some alternatives.